# Google Drive API returns zero folder size for non-Google type files

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I need to get a size of all files in Google Drive folder. I'm not counting Google-type files (Google Sheets, etc...)

Here is the code

```
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
# from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials as ServiceAccountCredentials

# Replace with the path to your JSON credentials file
JSON_CREDS_PATH = 'drivedownload-credentials.json'

# Shared folder ID
SHARED_FOLDER_ID = 'XXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx'

def get_drive_service():
    # Load credentials from JSON file
    credentials = None
    if os.path.exists(JSON_CREDS_PATH):
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_service_account_file(
            JSON_CREDS_PATH, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        )
    else:
        print("Credentials JSON file not found.")

    # Build the Google Drive API service
    if credentials:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
        return service

def calculate_folder_size(service, folder_id):
    total_size = 0
    page_token = None
    while True:
        response = service.files().list(
            q=f"'{folder_id}' in parents",
            spaces='drive',
            fields='files(size), nextPageToken',
            pageToken=page_token
        ).execute()

        files = response.get('files', [])
        for file in files:
            total_size += int(file['size'])

        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if not page_token:
            break

    return total_size

def main():
    drive_service = get_drive_service()
    if drive_service:
        folder_size = calculate_folder_size(drive_service, SHARED_FOLDER_ID)
        print(f"Total size of files in the shared folder: {folder_size} bytes")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Getting zero size.

Comment: are there any file types you are checking or just really exclude google type files?

Comment: @Logan there are only mp4 files

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a service account you need to share folder access to the service account email. You can do this by:

1.) Clicking the **three-dots** on the folder -> **Share**
[image]

2.) Add the service account email
[image]

You can get the service account email from the service account details
[image]

Comment: Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Thank you. I granted the permission but still getting zero size. I checked that there are MP4 files in the folder. No success so far.

Comment: Hi @IgorM It was how I was able to replicate your error and make it work. Apologies if that did not resolve your concern.